# React fetch request for local JSON file returns index.html and not the JSON file

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I am experiencing some unexpected behavior using `react` and `fetch`. It should be very straight forward.

My code looks like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/dict.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
  }

 render() {
    return (
     <p>Example</p>
   );
  }
}
```

and my folder structure looks like this

```
- src
   |_app.js
   |_dict.json
- index.html
```

When I check the network it is requesting the `index.html` page which makes no sense to me. Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 3):

**Production**: If this code is going to run in production then `fetch` is not going to work here unless you have setup a web server to serve that JSON file, however, you could import the local JSON file instead:

```
import dict from './_dict.json';
```

Then inside of your `componentDidMount` you can just map over it

```
let results = dict.map((item, index) => {
   // ...
});
```

**Localhost**: If you just want to run this on localhost, then I don't see why it wouldn't work unless, and which I suspect is the case, your React app is proxying HTTP requests to a local webserver *(as is extremely common in Reactjs development)* and that local webserver is not setup to serve your JSON file up. So check your package.json or webpack setup for something like this:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

And configure the webserver running on that port to serve your JSON file up in response to a request.

Comment: oh ok, that's correct! so you can't make a request like that to a local file? I thought this was possible with jquery ajax methods?

Comment: https://www.slothparadise.com/how-to-use-jquery-to-grab-json-files/ - IM confused :-S

Comment: Is your goal to make it work in production or on localhost?

Comment: Websites can make an HTTP request to localhost but only if they live on localhost themselves, it won't work if your application is live

Comment: I suspect you might be running a server in the background, where all HTTP  requests are proxied to from your React app and that server is not setup to return the local JSON file

Comment: I also have the same problem. After found some instructions in creat-react-app's generated README, I applied the proxy configuration into package.json--also not working. Still finding out why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this file structure

```
- public
   |_index.html
   |_dict.json
- src
   |_app.js
```